# OpenGL ES '<<' does not operate on 'int' and 'int'

Tags: opengl-es, shader, bitwise-operators

I had this shader that worked perfectly with my Mac app. But now that I am trying to make an iOS version of the app I get an strange error. Here is part of the fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D image;
varying lowp vec2 fragTex;

 int LFSR_Rand_Gen(in int n)
{
n = (n << 13) ^ n;
return (n * (n*n*15731+789221) + 1376312589) & 0x7fffffff;
}

float LFSR_Rand_Gen_f(in int n )
{
    return float(LFSR_Rand_Gen(n));
}

float noise3f(in vec3 p)
{
ivec3 ip = ivec3(floor(p));
vec3 u = fract(p);
u = u*u*(3.0-2.0*u);

int n = ip.x + ip.y*57 + ip.z*113;

float res = mix(mix(mix(LFSR_Rand_Gen_f(n+(0+57*0+113*0)),
                        LFSR_Rand_Gen_f(n+(1+57*0+113*0)),u.x),
                    mix(LFSR_Rand_Gen_f(n+(0+57*1+113*0)),
                        LFSR_Rand_Gen_f(n+(1+57*1+113*0)),u.x),u.y),
                mix(mix(LFSR_Rand_Gen_f(n+(0+57*0+113*1)),
                        LFSR_Rand_Gen_f(n+(1+57*0+113*1)),u.x),
                    mix(LFSR_Rand_Gen_f(n+(0+57*1+113*1)),
                        LFSR_Rand_Gen_f(n+(1+57*1+113*1)),u.x),u.y),u.z);

     return 1.0 - res*(1.0/1073741824.0);
}


void main()
{

// calculations
gl_FragColor = fragTex;

}
```

Whether I use OpenGL ES 2.0 or 3.0 I get them same errors:

'<<' does not operate on 'int' and 'int'

'&' does not operate on 'int' and 'int'

What causes this problem?

Comment: Which device are you testing on? `<<` and `&` aren't defined under ES 2.0 so really the errors should be different. Are you sure you're actually getting an ES 3.0 context?

Comment: I am testing on iOS simulator. I tried kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2 and kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES3 with same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<<` and `&` appear in GLSL ES only as of version 3. You need to add an explicit request to compile as GLSL 3.00:

```
#version 300 es
```

You've then got a bunch of other problems coming. Unlike the desktop, the ESs aren't all that bothered about maintaining legacy features. So you'll need your `varying` to become an `in`/`out` and `gl_FragColor` no longer exists. You'll need to declare a suitable `out` for yourself, which may not be called `gl_FragColor` since the `gl_` prefix is reserved. These changes follow those made on the desktop.

So e.g. get Xcode to create its standard GL ES template. It's helpful for testing because the red cube should always appear (its shader comes from GLKit); the blue cube will be visible only if the custom supplied shader compiles.

Change the API to `kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES3` (it's line 105 of the view controller on the current shipping version of Xcode; I'm not using the beta). Then change the shaders to:

```
#version 300 es

in vec4 position;
in vec3 normal;

out lowp vec4 colorVarying;

uniform mat4 modelViewProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

void main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    c = a & b;

    // template stuff follows
    vec3 eyeNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);
    vec3 lightPosition = vec3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec4 diffuseColor = vec4(0.4, 0.4, 1.0, 1.0);

    float nDotVP = max(0.0, dot(eyeNormal, normalize(lightPosition)));

    colorVarying = diffuseColor * nDotVP;

    gl_Position = modelViewProjectionMatrix * position;
}
```

And:

```
#version 300 es

in lowp vec4 colorVarying;

out lowp vec4 my_FragColor;

void main()
{
    my_FragColor = colorVarying;
}
```

... you should get a clean build. Conversely try just copying and pasting:

```
    int a, b, c;
    c = a & b;
```

... without adding the `#version` directive and updating the `in`s and `out`s, and you should get the same error you're receiving.

EDIT: you can `#ifdef` on `GL_ES` if you want to unify your sources without updating your desktop stuff to a later version of GLSL.